# n times forEach in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.attrs_value = {color: ["red"], size: [45, 42], etc...}
```

I have attributes variables and its return from the database so, it may has other key as well like,

```
$scope.attrs_value = {color: ["red"], size: [45, 42], type: ["round"]}
```

Now, I need to have an array like,

```
for(var data in $scope.attrs_value.color) {
 for(var input in $scope.attrs_value.size) {
  dataArray.push({
   color : $scope.attrs_value.color[data],
   size  : $scope.attrs_value.size[input],
   quantity : "",
   price : $scope.price
  });
 }
}
```

so, i have assume static attribute like color and size but, need to make it dynamic so, `n` number of times it will create for loop and build an array.

Default attributes will be quantity, price so, we are not considered it.

I know this is not the complete information but, i will try to do my best to explain.

Result will be like matrix kind.

```
0: {color: "red", size: "45", quantity: "", price: "45"}
1: {color: "red", size: "42", quantity: "", price: "45"}
```

If two color(red, blue) and two size(42, 45) inserted then, result will be like,

```
0: {color: "red", size: "45", quantity: "", price: "45"}
1: {color: "red", size: "42", quantity: "", price: "45"}
2: {color: "blue", size: "45", quantity: "", price: "45"}
3: {color: "blue", size: "42", quantity: "", price: "45"}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Previous answer

Sorry if not, but if I understood you well, what you want is an array like:

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        size: 45,
        ...
    },
    {
        color: null,
        size: 42,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

For that, I think I'll go with this:

```js
// easier to write... Sorry, I'm lazy xP
var attrs = $scope.attrs_value;
// the resultant array 
var newArr = [];
// the keys of your Object -> ["color", "size", "price"...]
var keys = Object.keys(attrs);
// length of the longest array in your Object
var maxLen = 0;

// get length of longest array
for (var k in keys) {
    if (attrs[k].length > maxLen)
        maxLen = attrs[k].length;
}

// create resultant array
for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
    newArr.push({
        // accessing an element outside of the array
        // does NOT launch errors, it just returns
        // "undefined" value. If you want another default
        // value instead of null, place it here
        //
        // ex. -> attrs.position[i] || 0,

        color: attrs.color[i] || null,
        size: attrs.size[i] || null,
        ...
    })
}
```

## Edit

Okay, so if you want something like this.

```
[
    {color: "red", size: "45", quantity: "", price: "45"}
    {color: "red", size: "42", quantity: "", price: "45"}
    {color: "blue", size: "45", quantity: "", price: "45"}
    {color: "blue", size: "42", quantity: "", price: "45"}
]
```

Then is even easier! Try this:

```js
var attrs = $scope.attrs_value;
var newArr = [];

attrs.color.forEach(function(c) {
    attrs.size.forEach(function(s) {
        newArr.push({
        color: c,
        size: s,
        ...
    })
    });
})
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but, there is no static ```size: attrs.size[i] || null,``` code like size
And, I have updated the question for, what i expect in the result like matrix.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check if now I got it right ^^

Comment: Correct now, what i need is we have no idea ```attrs.color```, ```attrs.size```, or any one or multiple so, we not consider ```attrs.color``` as static, we need ```.color``` as dynamic variable and make inner loop dynamically.

Comment: Sorry @HIR, I don't think I follow you. What do you mean with a static/dynamic variable?